# How to cast System.Web.UI.LiteralControl to System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel

Tags: asp.net

I have created dynamic `panel`, `chk`, `lbl` now I want to iterate the each panel `chk`, `lbl` value how should I do that I am getting this error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel'.
```

my code

```
    try
    {
        foreach (Panel item in pnlrole.Controls)
        {
            foreach (Panel pnl in item.Controls)
            {           
                string st = pnl.ID;
                foreach (CheckBoxList chkbox in pnl.Controls)
                {
                    if (chkbox.SelectedItem.Selected)
                    {
                        strGridData += st + "~";
                        strGridData += chkbox.ID.ToString() + "~";
                        strGridData += "$";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: your label is `LiteralControl` ?

Comment: Well as the error message says, you can't.

Comment: Anyhow to get an answer you should provide the markup.

Comment: Do the controls persists after post-back?

Comment: actually i have created the pnl,lbl,chk dynamically when i am iterating the pnl to get chk value it show error